# Cache the information and keep it until refresh of the page

Tags: javascript, php, jquery, html

I have a html page can takes login username and password from the user and fetches the information from the database using PHP. I am passing the variable username and password to the PHP using javascript as i dont want to display the background process. Below is the code:

For HTML

```
<script>
function PostData() {
// 1. Create XHR instance - Start
var xhr;
if (window.XMLHttpRequest) {
        xhr = new XMLHttpRequest();
    }
    else if (window.ActiveXObject) {
        xhr = new ActiveXObject("Msxml2.XMLHTTP");
    }
    else {
        throw new Error("Ajax is not supported by this browser");
    }
    // 1. Create XHR instance - End
    // 2. Define what to do when XHR feed you the response from the server - Start
    xhr.onreadystatechange = function () {
        if (xhr.readyState === 4) {
            if (xhr.status == 200 && xhr.status < 300) {
                document.getElementById('div1').innerHTML = xhr.responseText;
            }
        }
    }
    // 2. Define what to do when XHR feed you the response from the server - Start

    var userid = document.getElementById("userid").value;
    var pid = document.getElementById("pid").value;
    // var image = document.getElementById("image").value;
    // 3. Specify your action, location and Send to the server - Start 


    xhr.open('POST', 'login.php');
    //xhr.open('POST', 'config.php');
    xhr.setRequestHeader("Content-Type", "application/x-www-form-urlencoded");
    xhr.send("userid=" + userid + "&pid=" + pid);
    //xhr.send("&pid=" + pid);
    // 3. Specify your action, location and Send to the server - End

}

</script>
</head>
<body>
<form>
    <label for="userid">User ID :</label><br/>
    <input type="text" name ="userid" id="userid"  /><br/>
    <label for="pid">Password :</label><br/>
    <input type="password" name="password" id="pid" /><br><br/> 
    <div id="div1">
    <input type="button" value ="Login" onClick="PostData()" />
    </div>
</form>
```

For PHP

```
<?php 
ini_set('display_errors', 1);
$servername = "localhost";
$username = "root";
$password = "";
$dbname = "dtable";

//session_start();
// Create connection
$conn = mysqli_connect($servername, $username, $password, $dbname);
// Check connection
if (!$conn) {
    die("Connection failed: " . mysqli_connect_error());
}

$upload = "E:/Diczon";

$str = '';
$str1 = '';
if(isset($_POST['userid'],$_POST['pid']))
{
  $userid = trim($_POST["userid"]);
  $pid = trim($_POST["pid"]);

  $sql = "SELECT * FROM template WHERE uname = '$userid' and pword = '$pid'";
  $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);
  $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

  echo "公司".'<br/>';
  echo $row['client'].'<br/>'.'<br/>';
  echo "第".'<br/>';
  echo '<a href="preview.html"/>'.$row['day1'].'</a>'.'<br/>';
?>
```

This code display the output on the same HTML page.

Now as you can see i have a hyperlink to another HTML page. In this HTML page i am uploading an image. so after the upload is complete I want to add a BACK button and link it to the page where it display the output after the login process is complete. But if i hyperlink the BACK button to the first HTML page it will prompt for login again. So please let me know how to keep the data on the first page and get back to it using the BACK button. Here is the code for the other HTML page.

Second HTML

```
<body>
<form enctype="multipart/form-data" id="form" action="login.php" method="POST">
  <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" name="image" id="image" /><br/><br/>
  <img id="blah" src="#" alt="your image"  /><br/><br/>
  <input type='file' onchange="readURL(this);" name="image1"  /><br/><br/>

    <input type="submit" value="Upload"/>
    </form>
    <a href="index.html">BACK</a>//Want to retrieve the output data using this BACK button.
</body>
```

Comment: Never use string catenation in SQL for user defined values. Use parameters.

Comment: Thanks a lot. I will consider it.

Comment: Consider encrypt the password as well.

Answer (score 0):

You must keep the user logged in. You can use session and/or cookie.

PHP Functions You'll need:

```
<?php
    //This function starts a session and must be called on your form HTML page, before your submit
    session_start();
?>
```

Than, you should be able to save your data from the database to your global  $_SESSION, like so:

```
<?php 
    //Avoid using * for queries...
    $sql = "SELECT * FROM template WHERE uname = '$userid' and pword = '$pid'";
    $result = mysqli_query($conn,$sql);

    $row = mysqli_fetch_array($result);

    //It's missing some validations here, you should consider it...

    //The magic is here, you're saving your client in $_SESSION
    $_SESSION['client'] = $row['client'];
?>
```

After saving in a $_SESSION, you'll be able to achieve your client on your new page:

```
<?php
    print_r($_SESSION);

    echo $_SESSION['client'];
?>
```

Comment: What if i want to display this output on a HTML page. For example, the PHP does authentication and fetches the result. But i want to display the output in a HTML page as I want to add that page in manifest.appcache so if there is no network connection even then users can navigate to different pages..

Comment: You can use [JavaScript Cookies](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document/cookie) or [Web Storage](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Storage). The good think is that cookies PHP talks with Cookies JS, so you can transfer one to another easily.